# wirte perl script for http post request with previous res d

Tags: perl, rest, session, http-headers

Writing a perl script to send multiple post requests on a single session. So whenever i am sending first request, it will return some session id. I have to do the next request with the same session id. How to include that session in http header.
I do not want to use any http:cookie header. Can i pass the session id directly in http header. ?

**Sample code (*not working*)**

```
$server_endpoint = "https://ip/nitro/v1/discovery/device_registration";
$post_data = '{"device_registration":{"device_ipaddress":"ip","device_family":"CB"}}';
$req = HTTP::Request->new(POST => $server_endpoint);
$req->header('content-type' => 'application/json');
$req->header('cookie' => 'sessionid=$sessionid;');    # can I avoid setting a cookie?
$req->content($post_data);
```

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how the service is expecting to receive the sessionid. You will have to find that out from the API documentation.

If the service is expecting the sessionid as part of the POST data, then you could keep the POST data in a hash for easy updating, and only serialize it when it's time to issue a request:

```
use JSON;

$server_endpoint = "https://ip/nitro/v1/discovery/device_registration";
$post_data = {
    device_registration => {
        device_ipaddress => 'ip',
        device_family => 'CB',
    }
};

$req = HTTP::Request->new(POST => $server_endpoint);
$req->header('Content-Type' => 'application/json');

$post_data->{sessionid} = $sessionid;
$req->content( JSON::to_json($post_data) );
```

But whether this will work in your particular case depends on how the service is expecting the sessionid to be delivered.

Comment: So if i want to see how it is taking from UI, how can i check that one ?

Comment: Like I said, you'll have to check the API documentation. Is this the service that you're writing for? http://support.citrix.com/servlet/KbServlet/download/30602-102-681756/NS-Nitro-Gettingstarted-guide.pdf That document suggests that the authentication token really does have to be passed as a HTTP cookie.